# Android Studio Adding Setting 2 Edit Texts in same Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a second Edit Text to this Alert Dialog. I've used a .setView() but it only will display one or the other. How can I make both of them show up in my alert dialog?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            final EditText priorityEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add New Task")
                    .setMessage("what do you want to do next")
                    .setView(priorityEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            String priority = String.valueOf(priorityEditText.getText());
                            dbHelper.insertNewTask(task, priority);
                            loadTaskList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Inflate a custom view with 2 edittexts inside and use the setView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.You add a `LinearLayout`.**

**2.Add `EditText` to the `LinearLayout` . And set `linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`**

**3.Use `setView(linearLayout)` to add `LinearLayout` .**

You can do this .

```
final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
final EditText priorityEditText = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.addView(taskEditText);
linearLayout.addView(priorityEditText);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Add New Task")
        .setMessage("what do you want to do next")
        .setView(linearLayout)
        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                String priority = String.valueOf(priorityEditText.getText());
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create();
dialog.show();
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works great!! I up voted but don't have enough reputation for it to show.

Comment: You can `import android.widget.LinearLayout;` .And try again .